# Trying to make getSize to work for canvas

Tags: java, android, awt

I keep getting "cannot resolve method" for  `canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());` and "drawLine in canvas cannot be applied". Please help

```
    public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private float width;
    private float height;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
            WindowManager wm = getWindowManager();
            Display d = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

    Point point = new Point();
    d.getSize(point);
    int getWidth = point.x;
    int getHeight = point.y;
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

    // Draw the minor grid lines
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    canvas.drawLine(0, i * height, getWidth(), i * height);
    canvas.drawLine(0, i * height + 1, getWidth(), i * height + 1);
    canvas.drawLine(i * width, 0, i * width, getHeight());
    canvas.drawLine(i * width + 1, 0, i * width + 1, getHeight());
    }
    // Draw the major grid lines
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    if (i % 3 != 0)
    continue;
    canvas.drawLine(0, i * height, getWidth(), i * height);
    canvas.drawLine(0, i * height + 1, getWidth(), i * height + 1);
    canvas.drawLine(i * width, 0, i * width, getHeight());
    canvas.drawLine(i * width + 1, 0, i * width + 1, getHeight());
    } } }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `drawRect` method is part of [`Graphics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) not [`Canvas`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Canvas.html) so you need to look into how [`canvas.paint()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Canvas.html#paint(java.awt.Graphics)) and [`canvas.getGraphics()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getGraphics()) work. The documentation should give you enough to get your drawing commands to work.